# how to get the value data of a value name within a registry key

Tags: javascript, html, registry

I have the java script below. I want to get the data of a value name in a particular registry key. For example, if the key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\windows\CCM\CcmEval and the value name is LastSiteCode, how can I get the data of LastSiteCode. How can I get this path in JavaScript?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
MyObject = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" )
function App() {
var code = MyObject.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\CCM\\CcmEval\\LastSiteCode")
   document.write(code);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Application" onclick="App()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Not getting the value of "code" variable in output after clicking on Button.So please tell me how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086563/check-if-a-registry-key-exists-with-wscript, and you might be missing one trailing slash \, like in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\

Comment: Hmm... Actually, I've never used ActiveX through JavaScript (so I have no prior experience on this issue), but I just read it's fully supported only on IE, http://www.ehow.com/list_6702546_browsers-support-activex_.html, so if it's not a browser issue, then could it be the operating system: "In principle it is not dependent on Microsoft Windows, but in practice, most ActiveX controls require either Microsoft Windows or a Windows emulator" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX  I hope the info helps. Good Luck. Happy New Year :-)

Comment: Happy New Year @jyrkim :)
I have tried on different versions of windows operating systems but still No Luck.
Any alternate to achieve this instead of using ActiveX.

Comment: hmm.. maybe HTML5 video tag, http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp